# How to make a Textboxt empty validation in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to make a validation when the user clik the jbutton1 if the textboxt field empty the jlabel value will show "Input name cannot be empty". I'm beginner.

Here my false code :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                      
        if(jTextField1.text == ""){
        jLabel1.setText("Input name cannot be empty");
        }else{
        jLabel1.setText("My name : " + jTextField1.getText() + ". Selamat datang di java .");
    }
```

Comment: Use `.equals` method to compare String.

Answer (score 1):

Use equals() instead of == as-

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                      
    if(jTextField1.equals(""){
    jLabel1.setText("Input name cannot be empty");
    }else{
    jLabel1.setText("My name : " + jTextField1.getText() + ". Selamat datang di java .");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `==` as it is not correct. `isEmpty()` method will do the trick. Make sure to `trim();` for removing any white spaces beforehand.
Try to use this :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                      
    if(jTextField1.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
        jLabel1.setText("Input name cannot be empty");
    } else {
        jLabel1.setText("My name : " + jTextField1.getText() + ". Selamat datang di java .");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure will do. Thanks GGO for informing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals()` method of `String` instead of `==`. To get Text from `jTextField1` use `getText()` method.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                      
    if(jTextField1.getText().equals(""){
    jLabel1.setText("Input name cannot be empty");
    }else{
    jLabel1.setText("My name : " + jTextField1.getText() + ". Selamat datang di java .");
}
```

Check this [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to replace all whitespace to check if the input has any characters and then compare the length or using .equals():

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    String text = jTextField1.getText().replaceAll("\\s+","");
    if(text.length() <= 0){
    jLabel1.setText("Input name cannot be empty");
    }else{
    jLabel1.setText("My name : " + jTextField1.getText() + ". Selamat datang di java .");
}
```